# Can I Nest OrderBy in .NET?

Tags: .net, sorting, sql-order-by

This doesn't seem to work as I intend.

VB.NET:

```
Dim x = Model.Discussions.OrderByDescending(Function(d) d.Messages.OrderByDescending(Function(m) m.Sent).First.Sent)
For Each d As Discussion In x
    ...
Next
```

I get this runtime error:

> Sequence contains no elements

There should be 20.

Discussions are collections of messages.

I want to sort my discussions by the age of the newest message of each.

### Clarification

I need to sort my discussions, not my messages.  I want to sort my discussions by an aggregate calculation: MAX(Sent) among the messages of each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need `OrderBy` in the inner query at all - use `Max` (or `Min`):

```
Model.Discussions.OrderByDescending( _
    Function(d) d.Messages.Max(Function(m) m.Sent))
```

Though in VB, I'd rather use a query comprehension:

```
From d In Model.Discussions _
Order By (Aggregate m In d.Messages Into Max(m.Sent)) Descending _
Select d
```

The reason why you've got the error that you did is, apparently, because you have some discussion with no messages; hence calling `First` thrown an exception. `Max` will do the same. I'm not sure if this is a problem with your data set (it doesn't seem like it's reasonable to have a discussion with no messages in it), but if it is, you need to use `Enumerable.Empty()` for an extra check.

Comment: All discussions do have 1 or more messages.  But in this case they had not yet been loaded from the database.  d.Messages.IsLoaded = False

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `.OrderByDescending().ThenBy();`

Comment: I don't think that sounds right.  I want to sort my discussions by an aggregate calculation based on the messages of each.

Comment: Judging by his query, it's not quite what he means. He wants to sort discussions by date of the latest message in them.